# In C on Linux, popen / system to "ps all > file" truncates all lines to 80 characters

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, system

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.
If I open a terminal and call: `ps all` I get the results truncated (i.e. 100 characters at most for each line) to the size of the terminal window.
If I call `ps all > file` The lines don't get truncated and all the information is in the file (There is a line that has ~200 characters)

In C, I am trying to achieve the same but the lines get truncated.
I've tried
`int rc = system("ps all > file");`
as well as variants of popen.

I assume the shell being used by system (and popen) defaults the output of each line to 80, which make sense if I were to parse it using popen, but since I am piping it to a file I expect it to disregard the size of the shell like I experienced when doing it in my shell.

TL;DR
How can I make sure `ps all > file` doesn't truncate lines when called from C application?

Comment: I think this is because ps is detecting that the output is a terminal and changing its behaviour. But I can't remember how to control that.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and invoking `ps all > file` from within a C program(`system` function) seems to work fine. It isn't truncating anything

Comment: You might consider using the `/proc/` pseudo-file system yourself (see output of `man 5 proc`) or thru e.g. `libproc`.

Comment: I updated my answer to include using `fork`/`dup2`/`exec` manually which should avoid spawning a shell process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a workaround, try passing `-w` or possibly `-ww` to `ps` when you invoke it.

From the man page (BSD):

```
-w      Use 132 columns to display information, instead of the default which is your 
        window size.  If the -w option is specified more than once, ps will use as many
        columns as necessary without regard for your window size.  When output is
        not to a terminal, an unlimited number of columns are always used.
```

Linux:

```
-w      Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.
```

### Alternatively,

You might have some success doing a `fork/exec/wait` yourself instead of using `system`; omitting error handling for brevity:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pid_t pid = fork();

if (!pid) {
   /* child */
   FILE* fp = fopen("./your-file", "w");
   close(STDOUT_FILENO);
   dup2(fileno(fp), STDOUT_FILENO);
   execlp("ps", "ps", "all", (char*)NULL);
} else {
  /* parent */
  int status;
  wait(&status);
  printf("ps exited with status %d\n", status);
}
```

Comment: Great workaround! Adding -ww did gave me as much characters per line as needed. If there won't be any answer that explains how to change the shell being used internally when calling system I'll accept it.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I've updated my answer with a potential fix.  Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Apologies, I originally used STDIN instead of STDOUT.